# Duplicate Primary Key in PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a table named 'link' in PostgreSQL database. Then I created another table 'link_copy' with same structure as 'link'

```
CREATE TABLE link (
id select PRIMARY KEY,
url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE link_copy (LIKE link);
```

I copied a row from 'link' to 'link_copy' that had 'id' = 2. After that I copied all rows from 'link' to 'link_copy'. I was surprised to see row with 'id' = 2 twice in 'link_copy'. 
If I had selected 'id' column to be primary key (which is UNIQUE NOT NULL by default), then why did it allowed the 'id' = 2 row to be inserted in 'link_copy' twice?

I am using postgresql 9.5 on Mac with pgadmin III.

[screenshot for final link_copy status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZwHy.jpg)

Comment: `CREATE TABLE link (
id select PRIMARY KEY, ... );` this not gives error ?

Comment: Show us  tables creation code, exactly as you have it.

Comment: @OtoShavadze I have updated the code. All the code ran successfully on SQL Editor. I have also added the final screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `CREATE TABLE` command to create a new table with the same structure as another, it duplicates the columns, but not all of the constraints.  Your `link_copy` table will not have a primary key defined after it is created this way.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the postgresql documentation for same: It states "Indexes, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, and EXCLUDE constraints on the original table will be created on the new table only if INCLUDING INDEXES is specified."

Answer (score 1):

Create table like below.  This will create all constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE link_copy (LIKE link  including constraints including indexes);
```